# Why Does a Resistor's Resistance Vary?

Tags: electrical-resistance, measurements, error-analysis

Whenever we try to measure the resistance in a multimeter, the value is not the same for all measurements. Slight variations are observed over several measurements. But why this happens? And can this be considered as 'random' fluctuations?

Comment: [Contact resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_resistance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A multimeter measures resistance by injecting a known current and measuring the voltage across the device. As John Rennie mentioned in a comment, the largest uncertainty in this simple measurement is due to the contact resistance of the probes. The error occurs since the same probes are used to both apply the current and measure voltage. There is also a unknown resistance of the wires and probes themselves, along with the contact resistance of the probes, in series with the device being measured. Resistance of the wires and probes can be subtracted by a differential measurement, but uncertainty due to contact resistances is increased.

A more accurate and repeatable technique for resistance measurements is the 4-point probe method. Two pairs of probes are used, one pair to inject current and another to measure the voltage. This method is less susceptable to error from contact resistance, since with a high impedance meter the voltage probes carry negligible current. Thus 4-point measurements are almost always used when measuring small resistances.